# Membership tables for two application

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have an asp.net application which is using form authentication, asp.net membership provider (ASP.NET 2.0).

Now I am creating another application which will use the same database to login into the application (ASP.NET 4.0).

how can I do it in simplest way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same provider on both applications. Simply copy <membership> and corresponding <connectionString> sections from first to second application's web.config file.